Optimizing Spring Application Performance by Moving Assets to AWS S3 and CloudFront
We have a Spring application hosted on an AWS EC2 server. To optimize the application's performance, we are considering moving all images and scripts to an S3 bucket. Our application, deployed across multiple nodes, utilizes an Application Load Balancer (ALB). Additionally, we already have an S3 bucket configured with CloudFront for CDN purposes.
The challenge we face is achieving this migration without making any code changes in the Spring application, instead relying on configuration changes on the AWS side (similar to setting up a reverse proxy in AWS). If there is a standard solution available in Spring that can help us achieve this, we would greatly appreciate your guidance, as it would be preferable to avoid modifying every page of the application.

You can set up a CloudFront distribution with custom behaviors to cache static file responses (e.g., /*.js) from your ALB. Ensure that your path patterns specifically target static assets to avoid caching dynamic content inadvertently.
This approach doesn't require changes in your Spring application code. However, you need to adjust your routing configurations (e.g., Route 53 if that's what you use) to direct traffic to your CloudFront distribution instead of directly to your ALB

Can you please explain with an any example, it will helpful a lot, since we are very new to aws. Thanks in advance

Check this video out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2o3a2YhQa0
Around 6:40 he shows how to setup an origin (your ALB) and around 9:00 he shows how to setup path patterns
